# EmberJS, EmberJS/Data and Sproutcore-Datastore

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

With the move from SproutCore 2.0 to EmberJS there was the namespace and Github repo migration. Core things seem to have moved to the http://github.com/emberjs organization Github account while there are some others that seem to have been moved to the "addons" account http://github.com/emberjs-addons.

I am currently investigating EmberJS for use with a RESTful server, serving up JSON.

My question is: **Do I use the new http://github.com/emberjs/data code or the older http://github.com/emberjs-addons/sproutcore-datastore code?** I would assume the former but I would just like to be sure as well as get some clarification on what is going on with the old SproutCore "addons".

Comment: Thanks @Steffen I just didn't have the 'reputation' yet to add that many links. :)

Comment: This question is now outdated. Use https://github.com/emberjs/data

Comment: I'm not sure the decision is so simple. As Steffen points out Ember Data still does not consider itself production-ready.  And there are other well-considered arguments against it as well (http://www.thomasboyt.com/2013/05/01/why-ember-data-breaks.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The emberjs-addons are ports from the old sproutcore ecosystem. They are not modified and it looks like they are not receiving much attention from the emberjs core-team. They are concentrating on the new "emberjs-data". However, the old datastore is production proven and the modified version does work fine with the current emberjs relase (0.9.3).

In contrast, while the rewritten version looks really nice, it is explicitly stated in the projects readme that it is not considered "production ready", yet.

Which one should you choose? In my opinion that depends on your project. If you are looking for something stable or you want to put your app in production any time soon, I would give the "old" sproutcore datastore a go. On the other hand, if you are just starting with your project  use the new and shiny "emberjs-data" but be warned that you might have to fight around some edges.

Comment: Actually I'm not part of the core team, but I went ahead and added all of the addons ember.js ready and put them on BPM. You can [fork my github repo](https://github.com/ud3323/ember-datastore) or just use BPM `bpm add ember-datastore`.

But yes I completely agree with Steffen. If you need something production ready use the datastore port from SproutCore 1.x and wait for emberjs-data to mature.

Comment: Great work. I'm already using your packages from getbpm.org. Have you already opened a pull request to get those name changes in the addons tree?

Comment: A lot of the changes already have pull requests from other people. But those that are not there we'll be posting those requests shortly.

Comment: Oh and if you're having problems with templates not running using the packages I uploaded to getbpm.org, [follow the fix](https://github.com/ud3323/bpm/wiki/Using-BPM-with-Ember) I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using ember-models with my own REST adapter while I am waiting for the ember-models one to be completed. git://github.com/ebryn/ember-model.git