# Emberjs data store example

Tags: datastore, ember.js

I'm new to emberjs as well as JavaScript MVC frameworks.

I'm looking through the documentation in https://github.com/emberjs/data but I can't seem to get mine to work properly. Is there an example of a data store setup getting and posting to a RESTapi?

Answer (score 2):

there is a tutorial linked in the emberjs wiki that uses another library for RESTful communication with Rails: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/wiki/Links

I have used the old sproutcore-datastore ( back in the Sproutcore 2 days... ;-) ) along a very nice post from Peter Wagenet on the Sproutcore blog: http://blog.sproutcore.com/sproutcore-2-and-ajax/ - it again is not ember-data, but concepts should be similar and the sproutcore-datastore still exists as an addon: https://github.com/emberjs-addons/sproutcore-datastore

It is not exactly what you are looking for, but hope it may help.

Comment: More on ember-data vs. sproutcore-datastore in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698985/emberjs-emberjs-data-and-sproutcore-datastore

Comment: Thanks for all the links. I'll check them out.

Comment: I would definitely not recommend sproutcore-datastore anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of an Emberjs app using Ember data adapter to make it works with a REST API.

https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example

Answer (score 1):

I recently created a sample app with a Rails backend as a personal exercise. You can find it here: https://github.com/bazzel/ember-sample2

There's no tutorial available, though the README describes how to get up and running.

Feel free to re-use and comment on it. Anyway, I hope it's helpful.