# How should I evaluate different data store components for Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Just in my reading over the last few days I've found at least three different extensions offering data store support for Ember: [ember-data](https://github.com/emberjs/data), [sproutcore-datastore](https://github.com/emberjs-addons/sproutcore-datastore), [ember-ezdata](https://github.com/wiredprairie/ember-ezdata), and I think I might be missing one.

This range of options gives rise to several questions.

Obviously ember-data is the "official" extension, but it's also pretty heavily fenced with qualifications ("This isn't ready for production") from the core team.

- How should I compare and evaluate these options?
- In the SproutCore 1.x series, development was usually done with fixtures, and the data source wired in later. Can any of these options support that sort of workflow? Can I load some production data this way (might change with release versions, but not user-editable) and other data from my back-end data source?

ETA: Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8698985/306084).

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'm expecting big things from ember-data, but it does seem to have a little way to go to be "production ready".

When I started using Ember, the ember-data project had just begun, so I decided to create a simple persistence layer of my own. I ended up with [ember-rest](https://github.com/cerebris/ember-rest), which is a pretty thin layer over jQuery.ajax(). You can see it in use in [this Rails example](https://github.com/dgeb/ember_rest_example). By the way, you can load JSON data directly into ember-rest without hooking into a backend.

I'm under the impression that sproutcore-datastore is no longer maintained. I've never tried ember-ezdata.

Another worthwhile option to check out is [ember-resource](https://github.com/staugaard/ember-resource).

I hope this is enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, Dan, that's helpful, but I'm still trying to figure out how to properly evaluate these different options.

Comment: You could view ember-data as a data manager. It acts as a client-side store for your data and all its associations. There is a single canonical record that corresponds to each record on your server, which you can look up with a call to App.store.find(App.Person, 1);. On the other hand, a library like ember-rest is unmanaged, and simply provides a conduit for moving data to/from a REST API into ember objects and array controllers. I don't have much experience with ember-resource, but it looks to be somewhat of a middle ground between these approaches.